# Discuss the pointwise and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Discuss the convergence and uniform convergence on $[0,1)$

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{n}}$$

For example , for the question how can I prove  $f_n = \frac{x^n}{n}$ convergence pointwise to a certain function  $f$ here is what I did so far , I fixed $x \in [0,1) $ but I’m having trouble computing $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n$

And for the uniform convergence I tried to find the maximum of $ | f_n - f | $ but it doesn’t go anywhere .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by that sum? Is $f_n$ the $n$th partial sum and $f$ is the series

Comment: To begin, you know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ converges for $|x| <1$ -- do you not?

Comment: @RRL oh I didn’t see that but thanks now I see what I can do ( use the bolzano weistrass critera )

Comment: That helps with pointwise convergence, right?

Comment: Yes and also uniform no?

Comment: Assuming  you use what you say above interpreting $f_n$ as the partial sum then you are on the right track for uniform convergence.

Comment: Putting it together $x^n/n \leqslant x^n$ proves pointwise convergence of the series by the comparison test.  Since $0 \leqslant x^n/n \leqslant 1/n$, the general term actually is uniformly convergent to $0$ which means you have to look further to analyze for uniform convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uniform convergence it is necessary that $\sup_{x \in [0,1)}|S_n(x) - S(x)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ where $(S_n)$ is the sequence of partial sums. You don't really need to know what $S(x)$ is to proceed.

For any $x \in [0,1)$ we have

$$\sup_{x \in [0,1)}  |S_n(x) - S(x)| = \sup_{x \in [0,1)} \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k} \geqslant \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{x^k}{k}\geqslant n \cdot \frac{x^{2n}}{2n} = \frac{x^{2n}}{2}  $$

Thus, with $x = 1-1/n$,

$$\sup_{x \in [0,1)} \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k} \geqslant \frac{(1- 1/n)^{2n}}{2} \underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow \frac{e^{-2}}{2} \neq 0,$$

which shows that convergence of the series is not uniform.